# Create Word (.docx) Documents Programatically With docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

i want to Load  a template word document and  add content to it and save it as new document. here is what i found :

```
private static WordprocessingMLPackage getTemplate(String name) throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException {
  WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(name));
  return template;
}

private static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
  List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
  if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();
  if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
    result.add(obj);
  else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
    List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
    for (Object child : children) {
      result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

private static void replacePlaceholder(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String name, String placeholder) {
  List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), Text.class);
  for (Object text : texts) {
    Text textElement = (Text) text;
    if (textElement.getValue().equals(placeholder)) {
      textElement.setValue(name);
    }
  }
}

private void writeDocxToStream(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String target) throws IOException, Docx4JException {
  File f = new File(target);
  template.save(f);
}
```

i created i sample.docx file in the drive D, and then i called the main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException, Exception  {
  WordprocessingMLPackage template = getTemplate("D:\\sample.docx");
  replacePlaceholder (template,"fayza", "nom");
}
```

unfortunately this is not working , it guess the template cant load , i tried but still not working, any help please

Answer (score 0):

You don't invoke writeDocxToStream?

Also, your code contains:

```
if (textElement.getValue().equals(placeholder))
```

You probably want **contains**, not equals.  Its always worth unzipping your docx and looking at the XML to understand the problem better.

In any case, this is over complicated and inefficient, since you create a new and potentially large List.

See instead VariableReplace in the docx4j samples, or use content control data binding.